# How long do simple payments made from the Adaptive Payment API take to send?

Tags: paypal

I have been reading through the Adaptive Payment API documentation from PayPal's developer page [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), but I have not seen any indication of when the receiver would receive their funds.

PayPal has two payment methods that I am aware of, one where it takes 3-5 days to transfer the funds over from a bank account, and another where the payment is instantly made to the receiver.

How long does it take for a receiver to get their funds? In the implementation I am thinking of, I intend to send money to a single user, but it needs to be instant. Is this achievable within the API? Is this an option you can specify within the API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when the transaction is completed the recipient has the money in their account instantaneously.

That said, the sending account must be in good standing and have sufficient funds available to avoid delays.

Comment: Thank you. Since this was first I'm marking this one as answer, but thanks to @lorefold as well.

Comment: Is this based on the funds in my own PayPal balance? What if I have linked a bank account and credit card to my account, but have no PayPal balance? Would it still be valid and instant?

Comment: @eluong Yes, I assume you are paying from your balance. However, if your account qualifies for PayPal Instant Transfer there should be no delays in the above example. https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ781&topicID=&m=ARA/

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending money using API (be it [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/) or [implicit Adaptive Payment](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment)) you will be using your PayPal balance. Payment will be instant.